# Place text next to Facebook icon

Tags: html, css

I want to place the text **Follow Us** on the far right next to the facebook Icon. I added `float:right` to make it appear next to the Facebook Icon but it's not working for some reason.

This is my code -

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color:#999999">Website Designed and Developed By <strong><font style="color: #00FF00"></font><font style="color: #666666"></font></strong>, Web Design Blackburn, Web Design Lancashire<span><h1 style="float:right">Follow Us</h1></span></a>
```

This is the site I am working on - http://loweraudleytyres.co.uk/dev/. Trying to edit the footer.

[Screenshot of footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Ysv.png)

Also the footer is hardcoded, so does require customisation.

Comment: Don't use `<font>` tag. It's modern era now. Where is your fb logo?

Comment: Where is the image ?

Comment: On the Far right. Il take a screenshot. You can check the link to get a better understanding.

Comment: @java11 `<i class="fa fa-facebook"> FOLLOW US</i>`

Comment: Your code doesn't have any images, besides ```font``` is deprecated and the CSS should be in a separate file

Comment: Im working with a theme so need to do inline style.

Comment: @user2796515 it doesnt seem to work. Something must be overriding it.

Comment: They aren't going to ever get very close to each other because they're in different columns and the "Follow Us" text is left aligned while the Facebook icon is right-aligned.  You need to read more about how the Bootstrap grid system works.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@java11 I wasn't able to add an image to my comment, so I'm adding as an answer because I believe it resolves your issue as well.[image]

Code: 
     `<li><a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/audleytyres/">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"> FOLLOW US </i></a>
     </li>`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It shows correctly on your image but not on the site. Not sure why?

Comment: @java11 I agree that is odd.  The image is obviously from your site.  I only edited the html in developer console.

Comment: the facebook logo is part of the wordpress theme, so its not my own icon.

Comment: Well, it's a font-awesome icon, right?  Not sure how that matters either.  BTW, I tested in Firefox and it works as well.  Why the down vote?  I am only trying to help.  I was trying to clarify the issue with the OP by posting an image, but couldn't put an image in comment.

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted you. I dont have a high enough rep to do it.

Comment: still have not solved my problem. Although your answer has been the closest.

Answer (score -1):

Put your logo and your text in a *a* tag (link) with the style `float:right;` & add `display:inline;`

Example :

```
<a href="#" style="float:right;">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="float:left;"></i>
    <span style="display:inline; margin-left:5px;">FOLLOW US</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Im working with wordpress, so the logo is from the theme.

Comment: It doesn't change any of this

Comment: The icon is added by the theme. So it's automatically placed on the far-right.

Comment: it's simply a matter of overriding the style of the image tag, probably with ```float:left;```

Comment: Thank you. Will try this out.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It must be some code preventing it from doing it. Probably from the themes scripts.